# Does a Huffman Binary Tree have to be proper?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, huffman-code

All the examples I could find for Huffman coding have had an even number of chars to work with. If it is an odd number of chars can the last internal node added to the tree just have a single child ? Or do I have to add a NULL node of some sort so all internal nodes have exactly 2 children ?

If it is the later, it seems confusing because I am not sure how you would have a NULL value for a char (because all values are being used as valid ASCII codes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An odd number of `char`s is no problem. But that wouldn't lead to an internal node with just one child.

```
  /\
 /  \
a    ×
    / \
   b   c
```

The way the tree is constructed ensures that all internal nodes have two children, regardless of how many `char`s there are.

One starts with a list of leaves, and then in each step, (the) two trees with the lowest frequency are joined by making them the left resp. right subtree of a new - then internal - node, until there is only one tree left. Each internal node in the final result arises from joining two subtrees, hence has two children.